# unable to parse multiple phone numbers via gsub and ||= ruby methods

Tags: ruby, algorithm, pdf

I'm currently working on parsing phone numbers into a PDF form. I'm making use of the gem `pdf-form` which also user `pdftk`. The phone numbers are return as JSON when making a request of a form service I'm using [FormStack](https://developers.formstack.com/docs/submission-id-get).

I created a `DICTIONARY` to map the field id in the PDF form to the field id in the FormStack JSON response. So in that way I could iterate over them.

```
DICTIONARY = {
    'Applicant Name'              => '66563757', #Name
    'DATE OF BIRTH mmddyyyy'      => '66563844', #Date of Birth
    ##
    'TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 1'=> '66563943', #Primary Phone - Area code (000)
    'TELEPHONE NUMBER first 3 1'  => '66563943', #Primary Phone - (000) 000
    'TELEPHONE NUMBER Last 4 1'   => '66563943', #Primary Phone - (000) 000-0000
    'CELLPHONE NUMBER area code 1'=> '66563947', #Secondary Phone - Area code (000)
    'CELLPHONE NUMBER first 3 1'  => '66563947', #Secondary Phone - (000) 000
    'CELLPHONE NUMBER Last 4 1'   => '66563947', #Secondary Phone - (000) 000-0000

    'TELEPHONE NUMBER area code 2'=> '66564485', #Phone - Area code (000)
    'TELEPHONE NUMBER first 3 2'  => '66564485', #Phone - first 3 - (000) 000
    'TELEPHONE NUMBER Last 4 2'   => '66564485', #Phone - last 4 - (000) 000-0000

     }
```

As you see, the phone numbers are break into first 3 digits area code, second 3 digits and the last 4. I created a library to parse this phone numbers into the PDF form field. The values in the `DICTIONARY` hash are the fields in the digital form in FormStack. [image]
`USER_DATA` is what is passed into `initialize(user_submission_data)` which is the users data when it fills the form.

```
class PdfScrie < FillablePdfForm

  def initialize(user_submission_data)
    @user_submission_data = user_submission_data
    super()
  end

  private

  DICTIONARY = {

  }

  APPLICANT_ADDRESS_FORM_FIELD_ID = "66563934"
  TENANT_REPRESENTATIVE_ADDRESS_FORM_FIELD_ID = "66564487"

  TELEPHONE_NUMBER_1_id = "66563943"
  CELLPHONE_NUMBER_1_id = "66563947"

  ADDRESS_FIELD_IDS = [
    APPLICANT_ADDRESS_FORM_FIELD_ID,
    TENANT_REPRESENTATIVE_ADDRESS_FORM_FIELD_ID,
  ].freeze

  PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_IDS = [
    TELEPHONE_NUMBER_1_id,
    CELLPHONE_NUMBER_1_id
  ].freeze

  def fill_out
    form_fields.each do |field|
      id = DICTIONARY[field]
      @user_submission_data
        .select {|fd| fd[:field] == id}
        .each do |field_data|
          if address_field?(field_data[:field])
            break_address_into_state_city_zipcode(field_data[:value], field)
          elsif phone_number?(field_data[:field])
            parse_phone_number(field_data[:value])
            fill(field, @phone_number_sections.shift)
          else
            fill(field, field_data[:value])
          end
        end
    end
  end

  def address_field?(field)
    ADDRESS_FIELD_IDS.include?(field.to_s)
  end

  def break_address_into_state_city_zipcode(address, field)
    address_by_section = FormStack::Form.parse_formstack_nested_attrs(address)
    address_by_section.each do |section,value|
       fill(field, value) if form_field_has_section?(field, section)
    end
  end

  def form_field_has_section?(form_field_name, address_section)
    form_field_name.include? address_section.upcase
  end

  def parse_phone_number(phone_number)
    @phone_number_sections ||= phone_number.gsub(/\D+/, "").match(/(...)(...)(....)/).captures
  end

  def phone_number?(field)
    PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_IDS.include?(field.to_s)
  end
end
```

However, when iterating over the `PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_IDS` only the first phone number is being parsed. When I run `binding.pry` `fill_out` method I'm able to see that the number in fact is the one I want to parse.

```
[2] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> parse_phone_number(field_data[:value])
=> ["201", "785", "9896"]
[3] pry(#<PdfScrie>)> fill(field, @phone_number_sections.shift)
=> "201"
```

However `CELLPHONE_NUMBER_1_id` is not being parsed, and I can't understand why is not.[image]

This is the `fill` method thats on the other library that parses it into PDF.

```
 def fill(key, value)
    attributes[ key.to_s ] = value
  end

  def pdftk
    @pdftk ||= PdfForms.new()
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your code correctly, the problem is that an empty array is not falsey.

```
> foo = []
# => []
> foo ||= [1]
# => []
```

So, after you've processed the first phone number, the second is never put into `@phone_number_sections` to be processed.

What you probably need to do is add the new captures into the sections like so:

```
def parse_phone_number(phone_number)
  @phone_number_sections ||= []
  @phone_number_sections += phone_number.gsub(/\D+/, "").match(/(...)(...)(....)/).captures
end
```

Alternatively, since it looks like it may be possible for the number to be added multiple times, you may have to do this:

```
def parse_phone_number(phone_number)
  if @phone_number_sections.nil? or @phone_number_sections.empty?
    @phone_number_sections = phone_number.gsub(/\D+/, "").match(/(...)(...)(....)/).captures
  end
end
```

Comment: The `PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_IDS` array will have the values `["66563943", "66563947"]` which are the field ids that map to the phone numbers `[{:field=>"66563947", :value=>"(347) 222-2222"}, {:field=>"66563943", :value=>"(201) 785-9896"}]`